# out.println() in Spark isn't working for me. Everything is staying on the same line

Tags: scala, apache-spark, printwriter

When I copy the exact same code into the REPL it works, but in the spark shell for scala it writes to the text file, but not on separate lines.

```
val out = new PrintWriter("TestAverages.txt")
for(i <- 0 to 10) out.println(i)
out.close()
```

It gives me 12345678910 out of spark, the code works in the scala repl however.

Comment: It works for me, are you sure you are running the very same code?

Comment: Spark Shell is a wrapper for Scala REPL. Make sure you launch this code in the same way

Comment: @nicodp yes it is the exact same code, i don't understand why it doesnt work.  When I print in the spark shell itself, it prints on separate lines, but when I print it to a txt file, it stays on the same line.

Comment: Could you please paste how you are running this code and the output?

Comment: import java.io.PrintWriter
val out = new PrintWriter("hello.txt")
for(i <- 0 to 10) out.println(i)
out.close()




the text file says
012345678910

Comment: So you open `hello.txt` and it says `0 1 2 ... 10`... that's weird. Are you running it from the Spark Shell?

Comment: Yes, and yes I am using the spark shell.  When i put the exact same code into my regular windows scala repl, it works

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Spark other than the REPL, which is simply scala with auto imported packages and Spark variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what is causing this, now that you mentioned you used Windows. The behavior of [PrintWriter.println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28%29): *The line separator string is defined by the system property `line.separator`, and is not necessarily a single newline character*.

So instead of writing:

```
for(i <- 0 to 10) out.println(i)
```

go likewise:

```
for(i <- 0 to 10) out.print(i + "\r\n")
```

Recall I added "\r\n" which means CR+LF so the line break which will be printed out is not platform dependent.

Comment: Could also be `(0 to 10).mkString("\\r\\n")`

Comment: What worked for me is without the double \\, just `out.println((0 to 10).mkString("\r\n"))`